# Python base conversion algorithm not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a Python script that converts arbitrarily large numbers to binary representation. For some reason, this returns a long series of zeroes until the last few digits. Why?

```
input = 237481829347283491234198027358096491872350934781238471203874128039741298374109837410983741902374921793047102934710923741902374

while(input > 0):
        print(input % 2)
        input = int(input / 2)
```

Comment: where you converting `input` in binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have exceeded the number of digits that can be held by a `float`. It's not obvious that you have a `float` but you do, it's generated by the division operator `/`. Use the integer division `//` instead.

```
input = input // 2
```

After you've fixed that, be aware that this algorithm puts out the digits in reverse order.